# BehaviorSubject with nullable type?

Tags: kotlin, rx-android, reactivex

What I'm looking for is something like `BehaviorSubject<Object?>`. Unfortunately `BehaviorSubject` throws `NullPointerExceptions` even if the type is nullable.

As per the docs, `BehaviorSubject` doesnt allow `null` as an argument to `onNext`. Same with `ReplaySubject` which I've seen suggested as an alternative to `BehaviorSubject`.

I'm storing a value in the `BehaviorSubject` in my backend that needs to be observable (by some `LiveData` in my frontend), but its not a value that exists for all instances, hence nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a nullable type with `BehaviorSubject`, and that is a good thing actually. (Some folks might disagree.)

I would recommend using a `sealed` class instead with an "empty" and a valid subclass, like:

```
 sealed class Profile {
   object Empty:Profile()

   data class Data(val name:String, val age:UInt):Profile()
}
```

This way you can distinguish between empty ("null") and available state.

So, just create the subject like:

```
val profileSubject = BehaviorSubject.create<Profile>()
```

Then handle the data according to the type:

```
profileSubject.subscribe { profile ->
  when(profile) {
    is Profile.Data -> showProfile(profile)
    Profile.Empty -> showProgressBar()
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is not with BehaviorSubject but instead with types. Contrary to popular believe, Object? is not a nullable object, it's an *optional* object where the value can either be an object or undefined.

What you want is this :

```
let mySubject = new BehaviorSubject<object | null>(null);
mySubject.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Alternatively, you can obviously use the value of undefined rather than null with your original code, either will work.

You can read a little more here : https://tutorialsforangular.com/2021/02/08/optional-vs-nullable-in-typescript-angular/

Comment: I should have mentioned im using Kotlin. Theres no `undefined` and the `BehaviorSubject<object | null>` syntax is not valid.